# Is it correct to say "hang out along" in this case?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, word-choice

My friend was hanging out with a girl he likes and I wanted to know whether when they hung out, were they with a group of other people or it was like there were only two of them hanging out.

I wonder if "did you two hang out alone" is correct here? Or are there other ways that I can say this?

Comment: No, *Did you two hang out along?* is ***not*** valid. There are probably other contexts were ***along*** and ***together*** are synonymous and interchangeable, but this isn't one of them. The correct form is *Did you two hang out **together**?*

Comment: did you maybe mean "hang out alone"?

Comment: **Do you mean**: "*Hang out alone*"?

Comment: yea sorry I misspelled I do mean "hang out alone"

Answer (score 1):

This is highly informal speech, but I have never heard "hang out along" as its own phrase and believe it to be unidiomatic.

However "Did you two hang out along with the band" is idiomatic. As FumbleFingers said, the phrases "along with" and "together with" can have very similar meanings although even then they seem to me to have very slight differences in nuance. I would interpret "along with" to imply a less close relationship than "together with." but that may be a personal peculiarity.

Comment: I'm not keen on the doubling up of prepositions in, say, *Did you hang out **together with** the band?* In fact, the only context where I'd really find it acceptable would be if "you" (the addressees) was a *plural* usage. Where the speaker is talking to *two or more people*, so ***together*** refers to the addressees "collectively" acting as a unit, and ***with*** refers to the band (who are being "hung out with" by the addressees).

Comment: But what do I know? I still have trouble getting my head around the preposition usage in *We're going down the pub. Do you want to **come with**?* - which has gained a *lot* of traction in recent decades.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Well I agree. Informal American speech includes a great many usages that I would not use to save my life. But the OP is asking about current informal US usage among young people. I cannot give him a wrong answer just because I think the right answer is semi-illiterate.

Comment: I think your "semi-literate" is a useful term here. I have absolutely no problem with extremely slangy / informal usages in general - indeed, I've often voiced the opinion that the ability to use profanity "correctly" can be a clear sign of a fluent / articulate speaker able to communicate well in any register. But if someone told me they were ***hanging out together with*** their friends, I'd tend to take that as a sign of *not* having a very good "ear for language". And I assume *learners* would rather not end up in that category simply for lack of being informed otherwise!

Comment: I suspect that we are disagreeing over trifles, but based on what the kids I tutor in math say, "My girlfriend and I were hanging out together with her friends" is the sort of thing I hear too often. But I am there to teach them algebra and calculus, not English.

Comment: Given your most recent example, I'm not sure exactly *what* we're disagreeing on (if anything). As I said (or *meant* to say) before, *My girlfriend and I were hanging out together* works fine for me, and I've no problem if ***we two*** did our "hanging out together" ***with*** [her friend or friends]. I just don't like the usage whereby a ***single*** person can *hang out **together with** [one or more others]*.

Comment: I look at it this way... *I went with him:* fine. *We went together with him:* fine. *I went together with him:* NOT GOOD!. My reasoning here is probably partly influenced by the fact that whereas I can just about accept ***We** went with him together*, I couldn't possibly tolerate ***I** went with him together*.

Comment: I agree completely with your previous comment completely.